# Leaflet.heat Do not change the radius when zoom in/out

Tags: javascript, leaflet, size, zooming, heatmap

I am using the leaflet.heat plugin to plot some heat maps. I have a problem. I want the radius of the points do not change the size in meters when I zoom in/out.

On version 0.0.2, of the circles change in a way the have the same size in pixels, but they stay smaller im meters.

In my case this is does not work because I color an area with the gradient and I need that the exactly same area stay with that gradient all the time, whenever zoom the map is.

I already google afternoon all long and did not figure out how to do it.

Somebody could help me?